# How to find the position of a value with foldLeft from a List?

Tags: list, scala, foldleft

I have a List that contains, 1s and -1s. The goal I'm after is to find the position in the List when the total is -1.

```
List[Int] = List(1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 
-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1)
```

But my code is not working.

Here are my attempts(I spaced the code out for better reading) Note: **`floor`** is the val that holds the List of Ints.

```
floor.foldLeft(0) { ( (x,y) => x+y == -1 ) }.indexOf(-1)

floor.foldLeft(0) ( (x,y) => {  (x + y == -1) {x.indexOf(-1)} }  )

floor.foldLeft(0) { (x,y) => { if (x + y == -1) { indexOf(-1) } } }
```

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong here. I'm really after the why more than the answer in and of itself.

Comment: All your solutions miss an important point about foldLeft. The value `x` takes is the type of the initial value, in this case, `0` and the type returned by the function should have this type. In the first example, it's boolean. The other two just don't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

The anonymous function (the 2nd argument to `foldLeft`) needs to return the same type as the 1st argument.

The `fold` and `reduce` families are designed to take a collection and reduce it to a single value.  It's not going to work for you here.

This will get you what you want.

```
floor.scanLeft(0)(_+_).indexOf(-1) - 1  // scan collection is 1 element longer
```

In this case `scan` produces a new collection with different properties/values that can be queried for elements of interest.

---

So if you *really* need to use `foldLeft`, try this.

```
floor.zipWithIndex.foldLeft((0,-1)) {
  case ((s,x),(e,i)) => if (s+e == -1 && x < 0) (0,i) else (s+e, x)
}._2
```

Pretty ugly because you have to carry around the current sum, `s`, and the index of where you are, `i`, and the current element being evaluated, `e`, and after you find your goal, `x`, you have to keep it around and unpack it at the end, `._2`.

Compare the result with the `scanLeft` version.  I think you'll find that the final `- 1` adjustment is needed.

---

Here's one other approach that has the benefit of bailing out early if/when the desired target is reached.

```
val floorSums:Stream[Int] = Stream.tabulate(floor.length){ idx =>
     floor(idx) + (if (idx>0) floorSums(idx-1) else 0)
}

floorSums.indexOf(-1)  // 38
```

Comment: are you sure indexOf(-1) works for every occurance? The element -1 appears many times in the collection.

Comment: @MrD,  the value `-1` appears twice in the resulting scan collection. `indexOf(-1)` returns `39` which is the first occurrence.

Comment: This is from Advent of Code day 1 part 2. scanLeft(0)(_+_).indexOf(-1) produced the right solution link: http://mo.github.io/2016/01/09/advent-of-code.html. No need for -1. Here for a tuple: https://github.com/jrohland/adventofcode-scala/blob/master/src/Day01Part2.scala Question is, how can it be achieved with foldLeft and why am I not able to achieve the desired result with foldLeft ?

Comment: As I understand it. With foldLeft, it is a curried function. And it goes foo.foldLeft(initial value)(total, next). So: foo.foldLeft(initial value)(total, next) { What can I do in this area to get my result, or am I in the wrong place, do I have curly braces in the wrong place ? Because all the first parameter is good for is setting up a inital value, all the action happens in the second parameter.

Comment: It's less complicated when you use the correct tools (`scanLeft`).  When you try to clear a drain pipe with a hammer it gets more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

There are two styles of solution to a problem like this where you may need to bail out partway through an operation (in this case a fold).

One style is to use a non-local return inside a `def` you write just for this purpose (note that `.zipWithIndex` turns every element into a pair of elements: the original plus the index):

```
def exceedsTen(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  xs.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(0){ (sum, x) =>
    val now = sum + x._1
    if (now > 10) return x._2
    else now
  }
  -1
}
```

The other style is to have some value that you can pass along to indicate that you're done--so you really do traverse all the rest of the list, but you don't do any work because you know you don't have to.

```
def overTen(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  val pair = 
    xs.foldLeft((0, 0)){ (si, x) =>
      if (si._1 > 10) si
      else (si._1 + x, si._2 + 1)
    }
  if (pair._1 > 10) si._2 else -1
}
```

In this case, keeping a running total and the index where you found what you were looking for takes a little more space but is arguably a little clearer once you're familiar with both forms.

In general, finding indices of things is a kind of a niche application; you want to *do* something not just find something and hang on to the position for later.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a nice use case for Streams?